# VMware API endpoint IP Address for OpenStack Autopilot

Tags: openstack, cloud, openstack-autopilot

First of all, I've found this [article](http://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/12/01/test-drive-the-openstack-autopilot-with-a-virtual-appliance/).

Now trying to deploy OpenStack on our VMware vSphere 5.5 environment.
However autopilot-config script requires **VMware API Endpoint IP address**.

I'm trying to set our wmware vsphere vcenter IP. This used by our vsphere client.

Checking says:

```
Error connecting to host xx.xx.xx.xx: Cannot connect to proxy. Socket error: Tunnel connection failed: 503 Service Unavailable.
```

How can I debug VMware API Endpoint IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same IP you would use on a vsphere client, so that is correct. What looks fishy is that proxy message. Did you set the proxy correctly, if you are indeed using one?